# Юникод с помощью unescaping-print

Tags: haskell

Добрых суток.

Только начал разбираться с языком, ещё ничего не знаю.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подключить кириллицу.

Делаю по инструкции. Пробую библиотеку `unescaping-print`, поставил её командой `cabal get unescaping-print.tar.gz`, потом запускаю `ghci`, и пишу команду `:set -interactive-print=UnescapingPrint.uprint`, но мне возвращается ошибка:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error: Not in scope: `UnescapingPrint.uprint'
```

Заранее благодарю, за ответы.

Comment: `cabal install unescaping-print`. Если нужно просто вывести строку с кириллицей (а не сложное значение, содержащее строку, например `["тест"]` или `Just "тест"`), используйте `putStrLn "тест"`

Comment: @extn, то понятно, но упражнения, по книге, делать неудобно, и списки с юникодными строками тоже не отображает нормально. Ваш способ не помог, там зависимостей много.

Comment: У него одна зависимость - пакет base, который идет в комплекте с ghc. (Нужен ghc 8.2.1 и выше)

Comment: @extrn, сейчас пишет, что пакет установлен, но в ghci, строку: `:set -interactive-print=UnescapingPrint.uprint` всё равно не понимает.

Comment: `<interactive>:1:1: error: Not in scope: `UnescapingPrint.uprint'`

Comment: @extrn, спасибо большое. С вашей помощью всё-таки справился.

Answer (score 0):

это помогло:

```
$ cabal install --lib unescaping-print
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]